# How can I use the print stylesheet on screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to display a print preview of my webpage. I looked for jQuery plugins to do that, but they are all outdated or unmaintained. I figured I could just do it myself (so I only have myself to blame <s>if</s> *when* it breaks).

The only thing I need is to be able to load the `media="print"` and/or `@media print` CSS on screen, by luring the browser and somehow making it believe the support is paper.

Is there a way to achieve that? Something like `$.media('print')` ?

I'm using jQuery in my project, but vanilla JS is also OK.

Comment: for what purpose do you need this? For debug/development, or for production?

Comment: It's not that simple, many CSS rules produce different styling on a screen and paper. You'll need a specific stylesheet to emulate paper on the screen.

Comment: @niklaz: I'd use it for production: a print preview that can be launched by JS.

Comment: @Teemu: I will use a dedicated CSS for printing, but I need to be able to use it on screen during the preview.

Comment: New window or iframe with a copy of the css without @media print.  Low maintainability though.

Comment: Depends on the stylesheet, but among many things, all the units based on the window size will be off. Like I said, you'll need a specific stylesheet made only for the preview, the actual printing stylesheet won't give you what you need. It's easy to test, see how you can [disable and enable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet/disabled) loaded stylesheets.

Comment: All modern browsers have a print preview feature build-in, right? So I’d say, call `window.print()`, and be done with it … Results will be closer to reality than anything else you could do anyway - this preview will take options like automatic headers/footers, printing of background colors & images disabled yes or no, and other settings into account, that you would not even have any JavaScript access to in the first place …

Comment: @04FS Good idea, that was my first go, but `window.print()` opens the "print" interface. In some browsers, you have a preview, in others you simply select your printer and don't know what you print. Example with Firefox: https://prod-cdn.sumo.mozilla.net/uploads/gallery/images/2017-12-07-12-36-00-1fdbf9.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only works with `<link ... media="print">`, not with `@media print {}`:

Use those lines whenever you would like to display the print version of your website.

```
$('link').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('media') == '') {
        $(this).prop('media', 'all')
    }
    switch ($(this).prop('media')) {
        case 'print':
            $(this).prop('media', 'screen')
            break

        case 'all':
            // Do nothing
            break

        default:
            // Don't display screen, speech, ...
            $(this).prop('media', 'print')
            break
    }
})
```

Note that how @Teemu pointed in the question comments: all the units will still be relative to the screen and therefore may be different on paper.